# Swipe google MapView to go to another scren/activity in Android

Tags: android

I want to go to another activity or screen after I swipe the Google Map View. But it's giving me exceptions. I am trying to achieve this using "**ViewPager**" API. Is it possible to swipe to another activity.

The exceptions:

> 07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806): android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView 07-23 12:22:08.906:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   com.sample.swipeusingviewpager.SwipeUsingViewPagerActivity$SamplePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(SwipeUsingViewPagerActivity.java:61)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:321) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:441) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onAttachedToWindow(ViewPager.java:563)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:6156) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1122)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:1127)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:765) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 07-23 12:22:08.906:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 07-23 12:22:08.906:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   07-23 12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-23 12:22:08.906:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 07-23 12:22:08.906:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(806):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  ... 25 more 07-23 12:22:08.906:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity. 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:291) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:264) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:247) 07-23
>   12:22:08.906: E/AndroidRuntime(806):  ... 28 more

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code so it will give more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Your log clearly states the reason for the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity

In other words: have your `Activity` extend `MapActivity`.

However, besides the obvious error, you may want to rethink what you're after. Even if you manage to get a `MapView` to work inside a `ViewPager` (which technically is definitely not impossible), what would the user interaction look like? Both a `ViewPager` and `MapView` use swipe actions as the main user interaction method. Which one should be biased? If it's the `ViewPager`, then you cannot pan the map. Vice versa, if you allow panning on the map, then you cannot swipe between different pages.

Anyways, just a thought. It's completely up to you of course. By the way, you may be interested in the [android-support-v4-googlemaps](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) project on GitHub, which will enable you to use a `MapView` inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks MH., As per your suggestion I tried, t's working now. But when I swipe in the map, it's not working. Is it possible to achieve both swipes i.e. swipes in the MapView, and swipe between different pages. please suggest me any alternatives to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I was trying to point out to you: you need to make a design choice for the user. I imagine you'll either have to disable panning on the map (making it a static view), provide enough area around it for page swiping, or add in some logic that allows you to pan the map up to a certain distance before the gesture is passed on to the `ViewPager`.